# Crossing national borders within the EU (Germany and France) as an unaccompanied minor

Tags: schengen, germany, france

I am a 16 year old Canadian citizen hoping to travel with my father from Canada to Belgium, then intending to take the train alone to Germany and stay in Cologne, where I would stay a few nights in a hostel (Jugendherberge/youth hostels in Germany allow those 14+ to stay alone with written parental permission, which I would of course have). I would then head on to France (Paris) by train and meet back up with my father there.

Is this a feasible plan or will I run into trouble crossing the German or French borders? Is it necessary to provide additional documentation (another letter from parent, proof of ticket out of Paris back to Canada?)

Comment: I am not a specialist, but as far as I know you can travel into Germany and into France with parental permission (just like you need for the hostel.) It is more likely that the train staff asks for it than that you will meet passport control, but both are possible.

Comment: What national border checkpoints are there that the OP would be questioned at?

Comment: On the trains between Germany and France, there is frequently border patrol. But they do not check everyone, but mostly go through the train and keep their eyes open.

Comment: I suspect that the *same* parental permission letter would suffice. A single letter describing your entire plan much as you have here should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Under German law, legal guardians are *allowed and required* to supervise minor children. The extent of this supervision depends on the age of the minor, it is possible in principle that parents allow minors to travel to another city unaccompanied.

On a page which seems mostly concerned with German minors leaving the Schengen Area, [the German Federal Police advises](https://www.bundespolizei.de/Web/DE/01Sicher-auf-Reisen/06Passrechtliche-Hinweise/02Reisen-mit-Kindern/reisen-mit-kindern_node.html) to bring a permission letter by the guardian/s (by both if there are two of them) which lists:

- The identity of the minor, accompanying persons if applicable, and the *travel destination*.
- Identity and means to contact the guardian/s.
- A copy of the data page of an ID document of the guardian/s.

This is supposed to simplify their checks to avoid child abduction by only one of the guardians or truancy by the children.

This [eu site](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/germany/index_de.htm) also mentions regarding EU nationals that such a letter should also:

- *Explicitly mention* that the child may travel alone.
- Be in the languages of the destination and home countries if possible. (I would expect that English will do better than a google translation.)

You should also be able to explain how you will pay for your subsistence while in Germany (not *necessarily* with cash in your pocket) and how you will travel on. Bring your passport (and for those who require it your visa), too.